# vertical spacing for itemize environment with powerdot

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, powerdot

I'm trying to increase the vertical spacing in an `itemize` environment with the `powerdot` class. According to the `powerdot` documentation this is achieved by changing some parameters values in the `\pdsetup{}` command, I have tried but my code does not change anything:

```
\documentclass[
    size=12pt,
    paper=screen,
    mode=present,
    display=slidesnotes,
    nohandoutpagebreaks,
    pauseslide,
    fleqn
    ]{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\pdsetup{
    itemize={labelsep=10cm,leftmargin=*,itemsep=10cm,topsep=10cm,parsep=10cm}
}

\begin{slide}{title of the slide}  
\begin{itemize}
\item  Hello 

\item Hello
\end{itemize}
\end{slide} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\pdsetup` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @mythealias Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @lockstep I could not get `powerdot` to work on my install, so I was just guessing the answer based on other packages.

Comment: @mythealias It was a good guess, though, and I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\pdsetup` before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use it this way for local changes:

```
\begin{itemize}[][labelsep=1cm,leftmargin=*,itemsep=1cm,topsep=1cm,parsep=1cm]
\item  Hello 

\item Hello
\end{itemize}
```

the first `[]` is for Powerdot options and a second `[]` for package `enumitem`